# How to configure Simple Event Correlator (SEC) to send info about mail delivery failure

Tags: logs, sendmail, logstash, kibana

My log file contains the following 3 log entries:

```
2017-11-16 15:50:45 1eFLV7-0003so-Cd <= <> R=1eFLV7-0003sZ-4v U=Debian-exim P=local S=1853 T="Mail delivery failed: returning message to sender" from <>
2017-11-16 15:50:45 1eFLV7-0003so-Cd => admins@xxx.com R=dnslookup T=remote_smtp H=smtp-51.xxx.com [xxx.xx.xx.xx] X=TLS1.2:DHE_RSA_AES_128_CBC_SHA1:128
2017-11-16 15:50:45 1eFLV7-0003so-Cd Completed
```

I want to have an email sent to me, when an entry "Mail delivery failed*admins@.xxx.com" appears in the log file.

How can I achieve this?

Maybe SEC - Simple Event Correlator can help me?

But the below configuration(pattern) does not working for me.

```
type=SingleWithThreshold
ptype=RegExp
pattern=Mail delivery failed: returning message to sender*admins@xxx.com
desc=Problem with mail admin@xxx.com
action=pipe '%s' /usr/bin/mail -s 'ERROR SEND MAIL' me@xxx.com
window=1
thresh=1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand, you want to match two consecutive lines that originate from the same input file. If that is the case, the easiest solution would be to use the RegExp2 pattern. In fact, SEC operates in multi-line mode at all times without any special command line switches, and the number of lines matched by any pattern is set with the 'ptype' keyword. Here is the rule that might be helpful for you:

```
type=Single
ptype=RegExp2
pattern=Mail delivery failed: returning message to sender.*\n.*admins@xxx\.com
desc=Problem with mail admin@xxx.com
action=pipe '%s' /usr/bin/mail -s 'ERROR SEND MAIL' me@xxx.com
```

In this rule, 'RegExp2' means "a regular expression which matches 2 consecutive lines". By default, these lines have to originate from the *same* file, but --jointbuf command line option lifts that restriction. However, under normal circumstances you would *not* want to use this option, since it puts events from all sources into the same input buffer for multi-line matching, but the order of events is not determined.

In the above example rule, please also note the regular expression:

```
Mail delivery failed: returning message to sender.*\n.*admins@xxx\.com
```

Since by default .* does not match the newline, the expression also harnesses \n for matching the newline character.

Finally, I would also like to invite you to post further questions about SEC to its mailing list (https://sourceforge.net/p/simple-evcorr/mailman/simple-evcorr-users/), since a number of experienced users are following it who can promptly answer similar questions.

kind regards,
risto

Answer (score 1):

You're using `SingleWithThreshold` and hoping the * will match two lines - it won't.  Try `Pair`.

Something like (untested),

```
type=Pair
ptype=RegExp
pattern=Mail delivery failed: returning message to sender
ptype2=RegExp
pattern2=admin@xxx.com
desc2=Problem with mail admin@xxx.com
action2=pipe '%s' /usr/bin/mail -s 'ERROR SEND MAIL' me@xxx.com
window=1
```

Anything you try needs to handle the fact that you have two lines of text, separated by a newline.  Many text processing tools will work on individual lines, and the asterix character won't get around that by looking at the next line as well.

Comment: Thanks for try but not working. I know that there are two separated newline.

Comment: `sec` does have `--jointbuf` and `--bufsize` flags to operate in multiline mode